# Collect only if result is not null

Tags: groovy, find, gradle, collect

I have a collection and I'm wanting to find certain elements and transform them. I can do this in two closures but I was wondering if it is possible with only one?

```
def c = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def result = c.findAll {
    it % 2 == 0
}

result = result.collect {
   it /= 2
}
```

My true use case is with Gradle, I want to find a specific bunch of files and transform them to their fully-qualified package name.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use [`findResults`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#findResults(Iterable%3CU%3E,%20Closure%3CT%3E)):

```
def c = [1, 2, 3, 4]
c.findResults { i ->
        i % 2 == 0 ?    // if this is true
            i / 2 :    // return this
            null        // otherwise skip this one
    }
```

Also, you will get `[]` in case none of the elements satisfies the criteria (closure)

Comment: That was right under my nose the entire time... Thank you. (Will accept as answer when the question is old enough)

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't quite do the same as in my OP? `findResults` stops after the first non-null element.

Comment: You've typed `findResult` not `findResults` ;-)

Comment: Ahh this explains why I couldn't find it, I was looking at the `Collection` docs, not the `Iterable` docs and the `Collection` docs only has `findResult`.

Comment: Yeh, it's hard to find some things in the docs... List, Iterable, Collection or Object are all candidate pages some times ;-)

Comment: Sort of confusing that `findResults` also allows you to transform the collection. Should be named `collectSome` or similar